# Debian's screen does not fit monitor size on VMware Workstation

Tags: linux, debian, vmware-workstation

I have installed a Debian 8.5 on VMWare Workstation and it works fine.
However I cannot have full screen size for the Debian guest in such a way that it fits with the monitor.

Though I installed **open-vm-tools** package on my virtual machine (as I heard that it replaces **vmware-tools**) but it does not work better : the "Fit guest now" option is still not available.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `open-vm-tools-desktop`.  The base tools are for server installations, and the desktop requires X, but includes better video support.